# Physical Server or a Virtual Machine SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, virtualisation

Is there a anyway to figure out via a SQL Script to know whether SQL Server is running on a Physical Server or Virtual Server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a script:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('computernamephysicalnetbios') AS ServerName
,dosi.virtual_machine_type_desc
,Server_type = CASE 
WHEN dosi.virtual_machine_type = 1
THEN 'Virtual' 
ELSE 'Physical'
END
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info dosi
```

If you have a CMS configured, run the below Script from your CMS against multiple servers:

```
SELECT dosi.virtual_machine_type_desc
,Server_type = CASE 
WHEN dosi.virtual_machine_type = 1
THEN 'Virtual' 
ELSE 'Physical'
END
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info dosi
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM or older then there is a CMD Command "**SYSTEMINFO**" which has information about System model.
OR
If cmdshell is enabled on instance then you can execute it from SQL Server Management Studio.

```
DECLARE @result int
EXEC @result = xp_cmdshell 'SYSTEMINFO'
```

> System Manufacturer:       VMware, Inc.
> System Model: VMware Virtual Platform

New columns (`virtual_machine_type, virtual_machine_type_desc`) in DMV `sys.dm_os_sys_info` are introduced in SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlosteam/more-on-dmv-changes-in-sql-2008-r2-sp1)

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell use below..

```
$Virtual = Get-wmiobject win32_computersystem | Where-Object model -EQ 'Virtual Machine'
  if ($Virtual) 
  {
  Write-Host "SQL Server Running on Virtual Server" -ForegroundColor Green
  }
  else 
  {
  Write-Host "SQL Server Running on Physical Server" -ForegroundColor Yellow 
  }
```

Read more https://mkelsawy.blogspot.com/2019/09/DetermineHostedSQLServerUsingPowershell.html